# Where is PYTHONPATH added?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, python

when I checked the PYTHONPATH with

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

the results is so complicated. I want to remove some lines. However, it s not in the bashrc,profile or enviroment file. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Results are:

```
/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/rqt_carla_control/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_waypoint_publisher/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_ackermann_control/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_ros_bridge/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_spawn_objects/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_manual_control/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/home/../carla-ros-bridge/install/carla_ad_agent/lib/python3.8/site-packages:
```

and it goes more on that. some lines repeat and paths are wrong.

Edit: I used `export PYTHONPATH=` directly from the terminal and didn't write them in a file. But, my question is, even if I didn't save it to any files, does the system write it in a file or not? Because I want to remove all this complicated PYTHONPATH.

Comment: no, I used the 'export' command to set the PYTHONPATH environment. but, there should be a file to be saved which I couldn't find.

Comment: @user535733 I know how to use bashrc and persistent editing. 
I couldn't edit the current PYTHONPATH because I couldn't find it inside any file. Is it clear now? thanks.

Comment: I found my answer, thnks.

Answer (score 0):

As this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH:%7E:text=%3Aexec_prefix.-,PYTHONPATH,-%C2%B6) indicates, ''Non-existent directories are silently ignored.''. So, there will be no problem with this complicated path.

[Other ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76471466/14982476)